# save multiple tabs to chrome Pocket extenson

Tags: mac, google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, applescript, automator

I use the Pocket extension to read pages offine on an Ipad, but it's tedious to click the icon for every page. Most of the time I open multiple tabs on one subject.

Does anyone have a piece of applescript or an automator workflow I can use for this?
[image: icon on the right side of he searchfield]

thanks in adv

Answer (score 0):

I found [this extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/save-all-tabs-to-pocket/hfgddihjgadjjgllbfoihbpjojbnbfpb/related), but I have not tested it yet.
or maybe iMacro for chrome could be an option.